# What is the tech behind AdventureWorks installer?

Tags: database, deployment, installation, installshield

Does the [AdentureWorks installer](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55926) use widely publicised installer techniques, such as a [CustomAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49b92ztk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), or does it use something more esoteric?  What is it using?

Comment: Looks like a custom engine, so no custom actions. Anyway, the installer UI doesn't look very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a self extracting zip that exposes a custom DatabaseInstaller.exe.   This EXE is a .NET 3.0 XAML/WPF application. You can look at it using Reflector to see the Microsoft.SqlServer.DatabaseInstaller namespace.

To me, it's custom junk and just another example of different groups at Microsoft just doing whatever they please.  It might be exposed as part of some MSSQL SDK but I'm not aware of it, if it is.